# Why does this FQL not return page info?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, social-networking

Why do neither of these two queries return results?

```
select page_id from page where username="coorslight"


select username from page where page_id=8310601338
```

If I go point my browser at http://www.facebook.com/coorslight I see their page. I found their page_id (8310601338) by liking them and then querying my likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those queries work fine for me in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20username%20from%20page%20where%20page_id%3D%228310601338%22)- check you're not forgetting to use an access token for a user who can actually see the page - the page is from an alcohol brand so is probably restricted to users >21 in the US, users >18 in the UK, etc. You must use an access token from a user that meets the restrictions in order to see the page.

Comment: Maybe thats it. I am using an application's token.

Comment: Then that's almost certainly the problem - you can't access restricted content unless acting on behalf of a user that can see the content